# Use SICP collection for racket from the command line

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I've successfully installed the SICP package for DrRacket; and I tested it by using the `inc` operator in the GUI. I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html).

However, when I run `racket` in bash, using the `inc` operator gives me an error.

> Welcome to Racket v6.6.
>
> > (inc 42)
>
> inc: undefined;
>    cannot reference undefined identifier
>     context...:
>      /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:88:7

Clearly, I haven't installed it properly. So what do I do?

**EDIT 1:** Additionally, the `1+` and the `-1+` operators give a similar error, for both DrRacket's GUI and `racket` in bash.

Comment: `inc` and `1+` are not standard, you should not use them anyway. Better use `add1`, which is supported in Racket...

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Not if you are interested in the SICP module language.

Comment: But as far as i remember, in the 2nd edition of SICP they don't use `inc`, `1+`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I'm using a reformatted version from here: https://sicpebook.wordpress.com/ebook/. This version uses `inc`, while in the video lectures of the original course they use `1+`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to include the sicp collection:

```
~$ racket -l sicp --repl
Welcome to Racket v6.6.
> (inc 4)
5
```

You can also just start racket normally and evaluate `(require sicp)` before doing any SICP stuff:

```
~$ racket
Welcome to Racket v6.6.
> (require sicp)
> (inc 4)
5
```